# tooltip to hide the data based on user selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs googlecharts. when user click on legend, corresponding data on the chart is hidden. Issue is with the tooltip. When user click on legend Laptop(blue color) and mouseover on the any of the bar in the chart,the data on the tooltip which shows Laptop should be hidden, but the tooltip is showing information of Laptop also. The same is working when user click on Desktop Legend and mouseover on the bar, the data on the tooltip which shows Desktop is hidden.
Could not able to trace the issue, any suggestion on how to hide the tooltip information displaying Laptop information when user selects the Legend Laptop to hide laptop information.
Please find the demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/DPFL53ztEvFassgKtUW9?p=preview)

js code:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['googlechart'])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    var colorIndex = 0,
        chart1 = {};
    chart1.type = "ColumnChart";
    chart1.displayed = false;
    chart1.data = {
      "cols": [{
        id: "month",
        label: "Month",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        id: "laptop-id", 
        label: "Laptop",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
      }, {
        role: "tooltip", 
        type: "string",
        p: {
            'html': true
        }
      }, {
        id: "desktop-id",
        label: "Desktop",
        type: "number",
        colorIndex: colorIndex++
      }],
      "rows": [ {
        c: [{
          v: "Jan"
        }, {
          v: 13
        },{
          v: "laptop tooltip bar1"
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }]
      } ,{
        c: [{
          v: "February"
        }, {
          v: 13
        },{
          v: "laptop tooltip bar2"
        }, {
          v: 1,
          f: "1 unit (Out of stock this month)"
        }]
      }, {
        c: [{
            v: "March"
          }, {
            v: 24
          },{
            v: "laptop tooltip bar3"
          }, {
            v: 5
          }]
      }]
    };
    chart1.options = {
      "title": "Sales per month",
      "colors": ['#0000FF', '#009900'],
      "defaultColors": ['#0000FF', '#009900'],
       focusTarget: 'category',
      "isStacked": "true",
      "fill": 20,
      "displayExactValues": true,
      tooltip: {textStyle: {fontName: '"Arial"', bold: "true", fontSize: "14"}},
      "vAxis": {
        "title": "Sales unit",
        "gridlines": {
          "count": 10
        }
      },
      "hAxis": {
        "title": "Date"
      }
    };
    chart1.view = {
     columns: [0, 1, 2,3]
    };
    $scope.myChart = chart1; 

    var hidden = [];
  $scope.reset = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
            var hiddenCol = hidden[i];
            $scope.myChart.view.columns[hiddenCol] = hiddenCol;
            $scope.myChart.options.colors[hiddenCol - 1] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[hiddenCol - 1];

        }
        hidden = [];
    };

    $scope.seriesSelected = function(selectedItem) { 
      if (selectedItem.row === null) {
            var col = selectedItem.column,
                colIndex = hidden.indexOf(col),
                colorIndex = chart1.data.cols[col].colorIndex;

            if (hidden.length === ($scope.myChart.view.columns.length - 3) && colIndex == -1) {
                window.alert("One seies of data should be available all time");
            }
            else{
                if(colIndex == -1){
                    hidden.push(col);
                }
                else{
                    hidden.splice(colIndex, 1);
                }

                if ($scope.myChart.view.columns[col] == col) {
                    $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = $scope.myChart.data.cols[col];
                    $scope.myChart.options.colors[colorIndex] = '#CCCCCC';
                }
                else {
                    $scope.myChart.view.columns[col] = col;
                    $scope.myChart.options.colors[colorIndex] = $scope.myChart.options.defaultColors[colorIndex];
                }
            }
        }  

    };
  });
```

Comment: I red your question twice and was not clear to me what you wanted. so what do u want?

Comment: Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/DPFL53ztEvFassgKtUW9?p=preview. When you click on the Desktop Legend(green color on right side) it will hide the data related to Desktop and on mouse over on any of the bar the tooltip should also not display the hidden data information. This scenario is failing when clicked on Laptop legend(blue color), data is hiding but the tooltip is still showing the information about Laptop if you notice in the demo link i have provided. Unable to trace and fix the issue..@yesIcan